# How to Pass ID through Short Code

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode

How to Pass ID and fetch post meta data through Short Code like `[my-shortcode id="12"]` ?

My code is like below.

```
add_shortcode( 'my-shortcode', 'shortcode_function' );

function shortcode_function( $id ) {

    //I would like to get $id value 12 here   
 
    return $id;
}
```

Comment: Actually, everything you need to know about shortcodes is already [well-documented here](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/shortcode/), so please take time to review it and other articles there before asking another question. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your short code function receives the attributes as the first argument:

```php
function shortcode_function( $attributes ) {
```

Here `$attributes` is an array, and the attributes/values are inside that variable,

e.g. for `[my-shortcode abc="123" xyz="789"]`:

```php
echo $attributes['abc']; // prints 123
echo $attributes['xyz']; // prints 789
```

You should also provide defaults and an opportunity to filter:

```php
$attributes = shortcode_atts( [
    'id' => '',
], $attributes );
```

This way if the `id` is missing you don't get PHP warnings, e.g. if we wrote `[my-shortcode]` by accident.

### Improving The Shortcode

First, lets add type hints. This will avoid a common pitfall/bug that people fall into:

```php
function shortcode_function( array $attributes ) : string {
```

Here we've told PHP that attributes is an array, and that this function returns a string, aka the content of our shortcode.

This give us:

```php
function shortcode_function( array $attributes ) : string {
    // get the attributes
    $attributes = shortcode_atts( [
        'id' => 'default ID value goes here',
    ], $attributes );
    $id = $attributes['id'];

    // generate the shortcode's content:
    return 'My ID is:' . $id;
}
add_shortcode( 'my-shortcode', 'shortcode_function' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ID by extracting the shortcode attributes. Check out the example below:

```
function shortcode_function($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array('id' => ''), $atts));
    return $id;
}
add_shortcode('my-shortcode', 'shortcode_function');
```

In this example you set a fallback ID of empty string. You can also set it to `false` if you want. In the array within `shortcode_atts` you can define multiple attributes and handle them as you please.

Comment: I would avoid `extract`, it can be dangerous at times, makes code difficult to read/understand, doesn't work with tooling and code editor helpers, and can overwrite important variables

Comment: Ah, I didn't know the use of extract was discouraged. Thanks for the info!